# function with optionals, generics and comparable does satisfy compiler requirements

Tags: swift, generics

Im reading up on some algorithms and im working on a binary search tree. I have made the following

```
class TreeNode<T: Comparable>{
    var value: T
    var parent: TreeNode?
    var leftChild: TreeNode?
    var rightChild: TreeNode?

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    // ... more stuff ...
```

Which works fine. I have search, insert and print up and running, however when im trying to implement isSame, to se if two trees are the same, the compiler wont accept any of my function declarations:

First i try:

```
func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode?, rightNode: TreeNode?) -> Bool {
```

Compiler tells me "Reference to generic type 'TreeNode' requires arguments"

and suggests adding , which i then do, but now the compiler wants me to insert a ',' after the last parameter

```
func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode?, rightNode: TreeNode<T: Comparable>?) -> Bool {
```

if I do, it suggest i add another :D

resulting in something like

```
func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode?, rightNode: TreeNode<T: Comparable>?,,,) -> Bool {
```

Compiler, I have obeyed your every command. What more do you want from me?

I can get around this by stripping the function of the generic part like this:

```
func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode<Int>?, rightNode: TreeNode<Int>?) -> Bool {
```

But im curious to what I have to do to make the function work with generic types?

TLDR: How do I make an isSame function accept these two generic arguments?

Full code:

```
import UIKit

class TreeNode<T: Comparable>{
    var value: T
    var parent: TreeNode?
    var leftChild: TreeNode?
    var rightChild: TreeNode?

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience init(array: [T]){
        precondition(array.count > 0) // test denne

        self.init(value: array.first!)

        for item in array.dropFirst(){
            self.insert(item)
        }
    }

    func insert(_ newValue: T){
        if newValue < self.value {

            if leftChild == nil {
                leftChild = TreeNode(value: newValue)
                leftChild?.parent = self
            } else {
                leftChild!.insert(newValue)
            }
        }
        else {

            if rightChild == nil {
                rightChild = TreeNode(value: newValue)
                rightChild?.parent = self
            } else {
                rightChild!.insert(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    func search(_ targetValue: T) -> Bool{

        if targetValue < self.value{
            if let leftChild = leftChild{
                return leftChild.search(targetValue)
            }
        }
        if targetValue > self.value{
            if let rightChild = rightChild{
                return rightChild.search(targetValue)
            }
        }
        if targetValue == value{
            print("found \(targetValue)")
            return true
        }
        print("did not find \(targetValue)")
        return false
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions

extension TreeNode: CustomStringConvertible{
    var description: String {

        var s = ""

        if let left = self.leftChild {
            s += "(\(left.description)) <-"
        }
        s += " \(value) "

        if let right = self.rightChild {
            s += "-> (\(right.description))"
        }
        return s
    }
}

// isSame

func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode<Int>?, rightNode: TreeNode<Int>?) -> Bool {

        if ((leftNode != nil && rightNode == nil) || (rightNode == nil && leftNode != nil)){
            print("xor check returned false")
            return false
        }

        if leftNode?.value != rightNode?.value {
            return false
        }

        if isSame(leftNode: leftNode?.leftChild, rightNode: rightNode?.leftChild){
            return isSame(leftNode: leftNode?.rightChild, rightNode: rightNode?.rightChild)
        } else {
            return false
        }
}


// MARK: - Testing

var smallTree: TreeNode<Int> = TreeNode(value: 13)
var rootNodeFromArray = TreeNode(array: [7, 2, 5, 10, 9, 1])

// isSame test

let treeA: TreeNode<Int> = TreeNode(array: [7, 2, 5, 10, 9, 1])
let treeB: TreeNode<Int> = TreeNode(array: [7, 2, 5, 10, 9, 1])
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025618/generic-class-that-conforms-to-comparable-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is a global function, you can make it a generic function:

```
func isSame<T>(leftNode: TreeNode<T>?, rightNode: TreeNode<T>?) -> Bool {
```

This is exactly how the `Equatable` protocol can be implemented:

```
func == <T: Equatable>(lhs: TreeNode<T>, rhs: TreeNode<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
       && lhs.leftChild == rhs.leftChild
       && lhs.rightChild == rhs.rightChild
}
```

Note that the `Equatable` protocol doesn't need optional parameters. The comparison with `nil` is handled automatically.

Then you can simply compare using `leftNode == rightNode`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the isSame function inside the class like this:

```
class TreeNode<T: Comparable> {

    // code here

    class func isSame(leftNode: TreeNode<T>?, rightNode: TreeNode<T>?) -> Bool {
        // code here
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will consider that. My thought was that if i wanted to compare two entire trees, it would be wierd to call it from inside a tree :D

I made my function accept two trees by using the following code from the outside of the tree

func isSame<T: Comparable>(leftNode: TreeNode<T>?, rightNode: TreeNode<T>?) -> Bool { ... }

It seems swift likes to have the the generic information before the arguments!

Comment: Because it is a class function you don't call it on an instance, you call it on the class itself. Similar to a global function but nicely contained in the class :)