# Can Comparable protocol be generic?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Consider this struct:

```
struct Person : Comparable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

extension Person {
    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.age == rhs.age && lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

`Person` structs now sort by name.

But what if I want to be able to sort by either `name` or `age`, is there a way to make the `<` func generic ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025618/generic-class-that-conforms-to-comparable-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025618/generic-class-that-conforms-to-comparable-in-swift)

Comment: Saw that already, but don't think it is a duplicate. Please elaborate why you think it is (besides the title). Thanks.

Comment: How will you decide at runtime whether to sort by name or age?

Comment: Eg in a tableView, the user could sort by name, age, etc. I know an alternatve is `.sorted( by: { $0.name < $1.name })`, but wanted to see how this would work with the `Comparable` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a protocol generic. There are two ways to solve your problem:

You could create a wrapper struct which only contains a Person value, but sorts by a different combination of properties.

Alternatively, you could think of a way to compose methods that compare two things. We've done this in a Swift Talk episode: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E19-from-runtime-programming-to-functions (if you don't want to watch the video, you can read the transcript).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Person : Comparable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let compareByAge: Bool
}

extension Person {
    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        if compareByAge {
            return lhs.age < rhs.age
        }
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    if compareByAge {
        return lhs.age == rhs.age
    }
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

Comment: That could work, but if I have more properties (lastName, address, etc), then there will a lot of if-else code. Really looking to be able to pass the key of the property to the compare function. But maybe that's not possible?

Comment: You can create your own library if you want a comparing function that accepts a third argument. Assuming you want to use the built-in Comparable, the only difference can be in the items' internal state.

Comment: You could use an enum/switch to clean up the if/thens somewhat, although it of course isn't as elegant as passing a parameter would be.